# Not able to figure out sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, node-mysql

i am new to sql and need help with a query. I have two tables user and user_family which contains data like

**USER**

| ID | Date-Of-birth | User_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-21 | 28371 |
| 2 | 2021-04-17 | 28372 |

**USER_FAMILY**

| ID | family_detail_id | User_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 28371 |
| 2 | 1 | 28374 |
| 3 | 1 | 28375 |
| 4 | 2 | 28372 |
| 5 | 2 | 28373 |
| 6 | 2 | 28378 |
| 7 | 2 | 28379 |

i want to run a query which checks if current date in equal to someones dob in my user table, if yes i want to return all entries from user_family table which has same family_detail_id to someone whose dob has been matched. 
Suppose if the current date is 2021-05-21 then the result should be,

| ID | family_detail_id | User_Id | dob | birthday_user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 28374 | 2021-05-21 | 28371 |
| 3 | 1 | 28375 | 2021-05-21 | 28371 |

Comment: It is not clear what the relationship is between the table.  The naming conventions seem rather arcane.  What does a `user` table have both an `id` and a `user_id`?  Why aren't all users in the `user` table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join on the `family_detail_id`,

```
select f2.*
from user u join user_family f on f.id=u.id
join user_family f2 on f2.family_detail_id=f.family_detail_id
where u.Date_Of_birth=currdate();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9dba8205a21066eb5ffd863997be7951)

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there any way in the result instead of making entry of the user whose date of birth matches current day, we only make entry of users having same family_detail_id as the users whose birthday matches current day along with that add a row name 'birthday_user_id' which will store user_id of user whose birthday matches current day.

Comment: I've updated the resultant table in description, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `exists`.  Assuming that `user.id` matches to `user_family.family_detail_id`, then this looks like:

```
select uf.*
from user_family uf
where exists (select 1
              from user u
              where u.family_detail_id = u.id and
                    u.dob = curdate()
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query, assuming USER_ID is the linking column between the two tables -

```
select uf1.*
from user_family uf1 
where uf1.family_detail_id in
(select uf.family_detail_id 
from user_family uf 
inner join user u on u.user_id = uf.user_id
where u.Date-Of-birth = CURDATE());  --DATE(u.Date-Of-birth) = CURDATE()
```

HTH!